# CERN ROOT's Objects Ownership and C++11 Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, root-framework

I am trying to understand how  smart pointers are expected to live with ROOT object ownership scheme. I didn't have to go very far. Look at this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "TH1F.h"
#include "TFile.h"

int main()
{
  TFile f("out.root", "recreate");
  f.cd();
  std::unique_ptr<TH1F> h {new TH1F("h", "h", 100, -5, 5)};
  h->FillRandom("gaus", 10000);
  h->Write();
  f.Close();

  return 0;
}
```

The histogram which is handled by a unique pointer was owned by the current gDirectory. Since I politely closed the file before I exit my program the histogram was destroyed by ROOT memory management guy. Now at the end of main() my pointer goes out of scope and its resource needs to be freed, but it has already been freed!

I haven't found any resources on how ROOT object ownership/memory management is expected to live with C++11 smart pointers.

My question to you, do you use smart pointers in code where ROOT objects management is turned on? Do you use C++11 smart pointers in your HENP experiment?

Comment: If ROOT really takes care of ownership, why would you want this to work with a unique_ptr? I don't think this particular part of ROOT is designed to work with smart pointers (or smart anything.)

Comment: Well, I want to understand what are the different experiments'/users' guidelines on using smart pointers in code that handles ROOT objects. If the modern C++ code is expected to get rid of naked pointers then we expect to see more smart pointers in programmers' codes. So should we just ban the use of smart pointers to handle ROOT objects? Turn off ROOT objects management? Other plans from ROOT to get around this?

Comment: Sure, but you only should use smart pointers when you need them. If something already owns the dynamically allocated object, you can't try to take ownership, unless the owner has some kind of release mechanism. Also note that most of this was probably "designed" in the pre-modern era. One approach I have seen is to hide all this memory management behind more modern interfaces that do not seem rely on global objects and strange conventions.

Comment: Also, IIRC, re-designing those old corners of ROOT to adopt modern C++ idioms would be quite hard because it follows a maximal coupling design principle. You cant touch one thing without breaking everything else. But you can isolate yourself from the whole mess.

Comment: As far as I can tell from your code, h does not anything to f.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `TH1::AddDirectory(false)`, you will manage the histograms and then there will be no problem using smart pointers.

Comment: My question was how to make the ROOT object ownership **live** with smart pointers. Not how to turn ROOT objects management off.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `std::unique_ptr`, you really want it to be the sole owner of the object. You can turn off ROOT's object ownership for one histogram with `h->SetDirectory`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "TH1F.h"
#include "TFile.h"

int main()
{
  TFile f("out.root", "recreate");
  f.cd();
  std::unique_ptr<TH1F> h {new TH1F("h", "h", 100, -5, 5)};
  h->SetDirectory(0);
  h->FillRandom("gaus", 10000);
  h->Write();
  f.Close();

  return 0;
}
```

This way you still have ROOT's object ownership for all other histograms, but you can own this one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would guess to make unique_ptr and ROOT happily married, you have to use custom deleter.

In custom deleter you have to check if histogram still alive and delete it, otherwise make it no-op

Something like (in pseudocode)

```
auto deleter = [](TH1F* p) { key = FindKey(p->Name); if (key) delete p };

std::unique_ptr<TH1F, decltype(deleter)> h{new TH1F("h", "h", 100, -5, 5), deleter};
```

more complex schemes could be devised...

Comment: Except how would you know if it has been deleted?

Comment: @juanchopanza IIRC (I dealt with ROOT long time ago), you have to check key by name just as I proposed. If key is non-NULL, it is in current context and could be deleted.

Comment: You can check by name like this, but you have to *know* the name. Obviously calling `p->Name` doesn't work if `p` has already been deleted. If `p` has been deleted, this just segfaults.

Comment: Even worse, even if you store the name some other way, a new object can now have the same name if `p` has been deleted, and so this would still try to `delete p`.